# Set Default Admin Screen options & Metabox Order

Tags: metabox

I am desperately looking for some way (any way) to set default "screen options" and metabox order through the functions.php file. does anyone have any help they can provide here?

Comment: 2014 Update: For those who just need to reorder meta boxes, see [Nabil's answer below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159510/10388).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Setting the order of meta boxes on post edit pages

You will need to remove the meta boxes, and add them again in the order you want.

To disable meta boxes: (customize to your needs, look at the metabox id in the html code to know which name you should use as first parameter of the functions)

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {

    remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'core');

    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'post', 'core');

    ...
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

After removing them, you can use the add_meta_box function to add them at new positions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box. The order of the meta boxes depends on the order in which you call the add_meta_box function. E.g.: with the following code snippet, the comments meta box will be before the custom fields meta box.

```
function my_add_meta_boxes( $post_type, $post ) {
    if ( ('publish' == $post->post_status || 'private' == $post->post_status) && post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments') )
        add_meta_box('commentsdiv', __('Comments'), 'post_comment_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'core');

    if ( post_type_supports($post_type, 'custom-fields') )
        add_meta_box('postcustom', __('Custom Fields'), 'post_custom_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'core');

    ...
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );
```

You may want to look at the file wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php

### Setting which columns title show up on the post list page

You need to use the filter manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns. E.g.: the following snippet will remove the comments column.

```
function my_remove_columns( $posts_columns ) {
    unset( $posts_columns['comments'] );

    return $posts_columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_post_posts_columns', 'my_remove_columns' );
```

### Setting the default results to be shown on the post list page

Use the filters 'edit_{$post_type}_per_page' and 'edit_posts_per_page'.

```
function my_edit_post_per_page( $per_page, $post_type ) {

    $edit_per_page = 'edit_' . $post_type . '_per_page';
    $per_page = (int) get_user_option( $edit_per_page );
    if ( empty( $per_page ) || $per_page < 1 )
        $per_page = 1;

    return $per_page;
}

add_filter( 'edit_posts_per_page', 'my_edit_post_per_page' );
```

To target a specific post type:

- use `add_filter( 'edit_{post type}_per_page', 'my_edit_post_per_page' );` e.g. `add_filter( 'edit_post_per_page', 'my_edit_post_per_page' );` for posts, `add_filter( 'edit_page_per_page', 'my_edit_post_per_page' );` for pages.
- or use a condition within your function. e.g.:

  function my_edit_post_per_page( $per_page, $post_type ) {

  ```
  if( $post_type == 'post' ) {
      $edit_per_page = 'edit_' . $post_type . '_per_page';
      $per_page = (int) get_user_option( $edit_per_page );
      if ( empty( $per_page ) || $per_page < 1 )
          $per_page = 1;
  }


  return $per_page;
  ```

Comment: Sorry, maybe i did not explain myself correctly. I was referring to the meta boxes on the post edit page in the admin area as well as setting the default number of posts to display on the admin post list page.

Comment: so technically this is not a question, it is really 2 questions?

Comment: I modified my answer. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @sorich87 thank you for your response however from what I remember there was no way to specific the exact order of each metabox or was there? Maybe I should be a bit more specific. I am basically looking for various code snippets which let me pre-set various options for all users without having to login to each account. Examples: setting the exact order of meta boxes on post edit pages, setting which columns title show up on the post list page, setting the default results to be shown on the post list page... things like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just attempted to utilize the code you provided for setting the default number of posts in the admin post list however this did not seem to be working. Does something specific need to be done if you are trying to change the default number of results for a specific post type? If so, there is a way to set it for all post list pages?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the code. I modified it. You will notice the $post_type parameter which allows you to target a specific post type.

Comment: @sorich87 your code does work but now if a user changes the screen options to show a different value the page only shows the value entered through the functions file. what I was looking for is a way to set the default options however if the user change the screen options manually it would show the user set option.

Comment: @sorich87 also... how would I set the options just for one specific post type without effecting the other ones?

Comment: @sorich87 could you possibly provide an example of setting the values for just two custom post types. Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: I added new examples.

Comment: one more example please.Lets say that you have 5 custom post types. Now, lets assume that for post_type1 you want to set the value to 5 posts, post_type2 set to a value of 2 posts and you want any other ones set to a default value of 10. Could you show what this code would look like? Also, is there an option one could set so that these are just default values unless the user set the value manually himself. If so then how could be force a value so the user can not change it? Finally, when you select "screen options" that value does not update/reflect the value which is actually being displayed.

Comment: For anyone who is just trying to reorder meta boxes, this answer is no longer the best approach.  See [Nabil's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159510/10388).

Answer (score 12):

In the following example, replace `{CPT}` with the post type name, like `post`, `page`, `book`, `event`, `imaginary`, `foobar`... So if you have a post type named `event`, you would need to add a filter for `get_user_option_meta-box-order_event`.

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_{CPT}', 'metabox_order' );
function metabox_order( $order ) {
    return array(
        'normal' => join( 
            ",", 
            array(       // vvv  Arrange here as you desire
                'customdiv-{CPT}',
                'authordiv',
                'slugdiv',
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

#### Notes:

- Along with `normal`, you can also have `side` and `advanced`
- The values are comma separated div ids, you can grab by view the page source code or you can guess
- Any metabox that exists isn't included in your custom order will be added automatically at the end of your list.

Comment: I was somewhat confused by the `{CPT}` nomenclature; to clarify, if you have a post type named `event`, you would need to add a filter for `get_user_option_meta-box-order_event`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a plugin that combines these codes pieces together so an admin can force the meta box positions for all users without coding.

Bad practice or not, when performing help desk with some less sophisticated users, it helps a lot to know what they are seeing and where it is on their screen. Forcing meta boxes to the same position for all users can be beneficial with certain users.

Ideally, users with role of admin could still reposition their meta boxes, but subscribers and contributors could benefit from seeing all meta poxes in the same positions.

Does such a plugin exist. I cannot seem to find one.

This plugin might even be an option as it just prevent users from moving meta boxes around, but it has not been updated in a decade.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/unsortable-meta-box/

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/267974)