# Customize Edit Post screen for Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

What's the best way to completely customize the Edit Post admin screen for a specific custom post type?

I have customized it to an extent already on creation of the custom post type - adding additional fields etc, but I want to remove many of the elements such like permalinks, preview post, disable quick editing etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some of these questions are answered here: [Set Default Admin Screen options & Metabox Order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/set-default-admin-screen-options-metabox-order/1402#1402)

To remove the permalink metabox:

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'my-post-type', 'core');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

additionaly, you will have to hide #edit-slug-box with css or javascript. see: [Loading External Scripts in Admin but ONLY for a Specific Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/loading-external-scripts-in-admin-but-only-for-a-specific-post-type)

To disable quick edit:

```
function my_remove_actions( $actions, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type == 'my-post-type' ) {
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'my_remove_actions', 10, 2 );
```

To change the preview link, you could use the filter 'preview_post_link', but it works only when the post has not yet been published.
So, the solution would be to remove the submit meta box and add your own modified one:

```
function my_replace_submit_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box('submitdiv', 'my-post-type', 'core');
    add_meta_box('submitdiv', __('Publish'), 'custom_post_submit_meta_box', 'my-post-type', 'side', 'core');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_replace_submit_meta_box' );

function custom_post_submit_meta_box() { // a modified version of post_submit_meta_box() (wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php, line 12)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Been searching for the answer to this for ages!

Also, is there a way to change where the Preview button in the Publish box links to?

I'd like it to link to mysite.com/video?id='id of post' or open up a lightbox with a video player

Comment: Hi again - actually I can't get either of those bits of code you supplied to work. The permalink metabox just disables saving changes to the permalink rather than hiding it, and I can't disable the Quick Edit link at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer. I just tested the quick edit code ad it works. You are talking about the quick edit link below the post name on: wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=sis_course, right?

Comment: Great, I'll have a look at the additional info you posted. I was able to hide the quick edit by changing 'hierarchical' => false in my custom post type. Doesn't seem to make a difference as I'm using the Post Types Order plugin to order it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing the submit meta box worked perfectly! It actually had to include $post between the brackets in your function - i.e. custom_post_submit_meta_box($post). So that's all three sorted :) There's quite a bit more customizing I want to do to both the list posts and edit post screen - do you know of a reference guide that details how to remove/replace all the different elements?

Comment: Unfornately, I don't know a complete reference. This one may help you: http://www.cmurrayconsulting.com/wordpress-tips/customizing-wordpress-admin/