# How to reorder meta box position?

Tags: metabox

I have a custom post type which have a lot of custom field that categories in meta box. The problem is how do I sorting the meta box in the order that I desired?

As I know there is only 'high','core','normal' and 'side' for positioning the meta box, which is not a practical way to sorting the meta box. Let's say if I set 'high' position for two meta boxes, how do I know which one is on the top??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/set-default-admin-screen-options-metabox-order

Answer (score 6):

In the following example, replace **CPT** with the post type name, like post, page, book, event,  imaginary, foobar...

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_CPT', 'metabox_order' );
function metabox_order( $order ) {
    return array(
        'normal' => join( 
            ",", 
            array(       // vvv  Arrange here as you desire
                'customdiv-{CPT}',
                'authordiv',
                'slugdiv',
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Users can drag and drop meta boxes and WordPress will save the order. So, in a sense, the order in which they were originally rendered does not matter.

You know which one comes first because when you call `add_meta_box` it simply pushes your meta box's args onto a global array called `$wp_meta_boxes`.  Whichever call to `add_meta_box` came first will be the first meta box.

Comment: I know, but I want the position to be fixed. I don't want to allow the user to change the position. Is there anyway to predefined the position by the admin, and then fixed it so the user cannot change it?

Comment: Why is your meta box that important?

Comment: Well, I just want better user experience.

Comment: @dev-jim can you solve this questions, I want to the same functionality. best

Comment: Maybe disabling the ability to drag it around is bad UX. Yet, what about redefining the order they are added at? Perhaps the CPT has a `register_meta_box_cb` in the `register_post_type` which will regard that metabox as first, but it would be nice to make sure that a later-added metabox can still display first by default.