# Get custom post type categories to show up in menus

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, menus

I'm wondering how it's possible to add custom post type categories as an option to add as a navigation menu item.

What I have:

```
$portfolio_args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio Items',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Item'),
    'description' => 'Allows you to build custom portfolio items and link them to categories',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio-item'),
    'can_export' => true
);

// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
register_post_type('portfolio', $portfolio_args);

$categories_labels = array(
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

// Register taxonomies for extra post type capabilities
register_taxonomy('portfolio_categories', 'portfolio', $categories_labels);
```

Which works fine. I can create new categories for that specific post type. What I want to do is be able to go to wp-admin/nav-menus.php, scroll to the bottom and on the left, see the categories listed under 'Categories'.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see your taxonomy, check under the `Screen Options` tab in the upper-right corner of the admin window and make sure the `Show on screen` check box is ticked for that taxonomy.

Comment: Hey Milo, thanks. So apparently I had to open up Screen Options and check 'Portfolio Items'... (the name of the registered post type) for them to actually show. Is that normal behavior or should the categories automatically be listed within the categories section at the bottom?

Comment: Oh ok, I see what happened. There is another 'Categories' that I can select that is related to my custom post type. That fixed it thanks.

Comment: Is there a way then to automatically show either the 'Portfolio Items' or 'Categories' by default?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how that part of the UI works. I believe the screen options are saved per-user as user meta data, and I've experienced some seemingly random behavior like you have, with it being hidden for a user but not another. I'll have to look into it more to see exactly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should already see this taxonomy on the bottom left under nav-menus, it works in the default them or any theme that supports `register_nav_menu`

I highly suggest you change the name for `'label' => 'Categories',` to something else, the default category meta box shows exactly this name already.

In order for the actual taxonomies to show up, you need to create some items for it and tag some post to it, or you can select "View All".

For example: I took your example and pasted it into twentyeleven and changed the label to "cats".

[image]

Comment: That's strange. It must be the theme I'm building but I don't really know what would have caused this conflict.

Comment: Ah lol see Milo's answer this one gets everyone.

Comment: I actually do/did see the Categories tab, except my Most Used and View All were empty.

Comment: I suggest changing the name, that label is already used in wordpress and might cause problems, and making some test terms and posts in this category. Also turn on debugging.

Comment: Great, just did. Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to automatically show either the 'Portfolio Items' or 'Categories' by default so the user doesn't have to select screen options > whatever?

Comment: Yes there are several question on here about that, like http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/set-default-admin-screen-options-metabox-order?rq=1 and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15376/how-to-set-default-screen-options