# How do you reorder the custom taxonomies on the right side of a custom post edit page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type with several associated custom taxonomies. On the edit page for the custom post type, the taxonomies appear to be in the order in which they were created. I want to change this order. How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming you mean the *(taxonomy widget metaboxes?)* postboxes on the edit screen, take a [look here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1402/15605) for an possible answer/idea. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the edit screen boxes for these taxonomies, you can do that by changing the `$content` and `priority` parameters in [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

> **$context** (string) (Optional) The context within the screen where the
>   boxes should display. Available contexts vary from screen to screen.
>   Post edit screen contexts include 'normal', 'side', and 'advanced'.
>   Comments screen contexts include 'normal' and 'side'. Menus meta boxes
>   (accordion sections) all use the 'side' context. Global Default value:
>   'advanced'
>
> **$priority** (string) (Optional) The priority within the
>   context where the boxes should show ('high', 'low'). Default value:
>   'default'

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box', 
 My Meta Box, 
 'my-meta-box-callback-function', 
 null, //unless you need the $screen parameter 
 'advanced', //change this $context parameter for placement
'default', //change this  $priority parameter for order within placement
 null // unless you need $callback_args 
 );
```